# Get Imagesource from Memorystream in c# wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, memorystream, imagesource

How can I get `ImageSource` from `MemoryStream` in WPF using c# ? or convert `MemoryStream` to `ImageSource` to display it as image in wpf ?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

```
using (MemoryStream memoryStream = ...)
{
    var imageSource = new BitmapImage();
    imageSource.BeginInit();
    imageSource.StreamSource = memoryStream;
    imageSource.EndInit();

    // Assign the Source property of your image
    image.Source = imageSource;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Additional to @Darin Dimitrov answer if you disposed the stream before assigning to `Image.Source` nothing will show, so be careful

For example, the Next method will not work, `From one of my projects using LiteDB`

```
public async Task<BitmapImage> DownloadImage(string id)
{
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        var f = _appDbManager.DataStorage.FindById(id);
        f.CopyTo(stream);
        var imageSource = new BitmapImage {CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad};
        imageSource.BeginInit();
        imageSource.StreamSource = stream;
        imageSource.EndInit();
        return imageSource;
    }
}
```

you can not use returned `imageSource` from the last function

But this implementation will work

```
public async Task<BitmapImage> DownloadImage(string id)
{
    // TODO: [Note] Bug due to memory leaks, if we used Using( var stream = new MemoryStream()), we will lost the stream, and nothing will shown
    var stream = new MemoryStream();
    var f = _appDbManager.DataStorage.FindById(id);
    f.CopyTo(stream);
    var imageSource = new BitmapImage {CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad};
    imageSource.BeginInit();
    imageSource.StreamSource = stream;
    imageSource.EndInit();
    return imageSource;
}
```